# Why doubly linked list code is showing memory error?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I just want to try a code for inserting and deleting the element from the **doubly linked list** but I don't understand why this code is showing memory error five times. When I remove the **memory error checking** part then this code works perfectly fine. Here is my code (below is just some part of the actual code)

```
struct listNode {
    int data;
    struct listNode* next;
    struct listNode* prev;
};
typedef struct listNode Node;
Node* head;

void DLLInsert(int data, int position)
{
    int k = 1;
    Node* temp, *newNode;

    newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    //Always check for memory errors
    if(newNode)
    {
        printf("memory error");
        return;
    }
    newNode->data = data;

    //Inserting a node at the beginning of the list
    if(position == 1)
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        newNode->prev = NULL;
        if(head)
        {
            head->prev = newNode;
        }
        head = newNode;
        return;
    }
    temp = head;
    while((k<position-1)&&temp->next!=NULL) //traversal
    {
        temp=temp->next;
        k++;
    }
    if(k!=position-1)
    {
        printf("Desired position does not exist\n");
    }
    newNode->next = temp->next;
    newNode->prev=temp;

    if(temp->next)
        temp->next->prev=newNode;
    temp->next=newNode;
    return;
}
```

Any explanation regarding this behaviour would highly be appreciated :)

Comment: You're confusing yourself `if(newNode)` evaluates to true if the memory was allocated successfully.

Comment: `if(newNode)` --> `if(!newNode)` or `if(newNode==NULL)`

Comment: Change `if (newNode)` to `if (newNode == NULL)`.  You have the sense of the test reversed.  `newNode` will be non-zero, and hence true, if the call to `malloc` succeeds (i.e., in the normal case).

Comment: Ohh I am sorry I interpreted it wrong! Thanks a lot for your help @Smac89

Answer (score 0):

I think the check you put is wrong. it has to be like below:

```
if (NULL == newNode) OR if (!newNode)
{
    //your code
}
```